# Excel VBA - GoalSeek cannot be called from User Defined Function

Tags: excel, vba, function

Here is the User Defined Function where I'm calling GoalSeek.

I put this into module, however it does not solve for the given context.

```
Function FindYield() As Double
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("N8").GoalSeek _
    Goal:=0, _
    ChangingCell:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("N9")
End Function
```

The same setup works as a Sub.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a **Sub** rather than a **Function.** Functions can only return a value to the cell in which they reside.

Comment: OK but in my case I'd like this calculation to be triggered whenever I call the formula. In case, I use Sub, I will also need to set some sort of button etc. to trigger the calculation, right?

Comment: You can use an **Event** macro................It could call *GoalSeek* whenever the formula is re-calculated *(automatically)*